# How do I change radio buttons in a sub category based on radio selection of master category?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

Okay, I have two radios per category. One is "allowed" other is "denied". Each category has a subcategory. the same radios are on each sub cat. What I am trying to do is if someone selects  "allowed" or "denied" in the main category, all of that category subcategory's are changed to reflect that choice, but allowing independent changes in the subcategory.

Each category and subcategory is dynamically created with PHP and MySQL using a loop. I know that I will need to add a unique id to each sub-cat for each main cat. Im just not sure how to go about doing it.

```
        <ul><!-- main category -->
            <li><b><font size="3">Users:</font></b>
                <p class="radioper"><font color="green"> <b>Allowed</b> </font>
                <input type="radio" name="modusers" value="1" checked="">
                <font color="red"> <b>Denied</b> </font>
                <input type="radio" name="modusers" value="0"></p>
            </li>
            <ul><!--Sub-cat -->
                <li><font size="3">Active Users:</font>
                    <p class="radioper"><font color="green"> <b>Allowed</b> </font>
                    <input type="radio" name="fusract" value="1" checked="">
                    <font color="red"> <b>Denied</b> </font>
                    <input type="radio" name="fusract" value="0"></p>
                </li>
            </ul><!-- End Sub-Cat -->
        </ul><!-- End Main Category -->
```

Comment: are you using jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using jquery 1.6 or later then this is the solution:

you have to add ids and classed according to your actual situation but this is an example,

```
<ul><!-- main category -->
    <li><b><font size="3">Users:</font></b>
        <p class="radioper"><font color="green"> <b>Allowed</b> </font>
            <input id="radio-users-allowed" type="radio" name="modusers" value="1" checked>
            <font color="red"> <b>Denied</b> </font>
            <input id="radio-users-denied" type="radio" name="modusers" value="0"></p>
        </li>
        <ul><!--Sub-cat -->
            <li><font size="3">Active Users:</font>
                <p class="radioper"><font color="green"> <b>Allowed</b> </font>
                    <input class="radio-active-users-allowed" type="radio" name="fusract" value="1" checked>
                    <font color="red"> <b>Denied</b> </font>
                    <input class="radio-active-users-denied" type="radio" name="fusract" value="0"></p>
                </li>
            </ul><!-- End Sub-Cat -->
</ul><!-- End Main Category -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#radio-users-allowed').change(function(){
        $('.radio-active-users-allowed').prop('checked', true);
    });
    $('#radio-users-denied').change(function(){
        $('.radio-active-users-denied').prop('checked', true);
    })
</script>
```

Comment: you will have to modify it according to your code, if you want it to change all the radios in all the subcategory then just use the same classname for all the radios.